# Python: How do I extract the value of column Z respect to a set of coordinates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns (among many), "X", "Y", "Z".
I need to plot it with surface plot. 
I am refering to https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html

So at the value Data["X"],Data["Y"] the surface should be Data["Z"]. And it is important that there is a colored surface that shows how high it is.

I went as far as:

```
a, b = np.meshgrid(data['X'], data['Y'])
```

Now I need to define the Z before calling

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(a, b, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

But this is proving harder than I expected. 
I tried:

```
Z=data[data["X"]==a & data["Y"]==b]["Z"]
```

but this does not work. Is there an easy way to extract the Z values out of a dataframe?

Comment: Add (brackets) around conditions: Z=data[(data["X"]==a) & (data["Y"]==b)]["Z"]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Not only as @Michael O. said I needed to put brackets around the condition. But I also needed to change the way the mash network was prepared:

```
list_set_x=list(set(data["X"]))
list_set_y=list(set(data["Y"]))
Z=[]
for x in list_set_x:
    Z1=[]
    for y in list_set_y:
        C=float(data[(data["X"]==x)&(data["Y"]==y)]["Z"])
        Z1.append(C)
    Z.append(Z1)
c=np.array(Z)

e,f=np.meshgrid(list(set_y),list( set_x))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(f, e, c, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```